# Python Pandas replace NaN with data from another row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes. Dataframe A contains course information, including the ISBN number for required textbooks:

| Course Abbreviation | Course Number | Section Number | Course Name | Course Instructor | Course Seats | ISBN No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACCT | 205 | 101 | Intro Financial Accounting |  | 30 | 9780357617977 |
| ACCT | 205 | 102 | Intro Financial Accounting | Grant | 30 | 9780357617977 |
| ACCT | 205 | 901 | Intro Financial Accounting | Grant | 35 | 9780357617977 |

Dataframe B contains book purchasing info and also includes the ISBN number:

| Title | ISBN | Binding | Edition | US_List |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 HABITS OF HIGHLY EFFECTIVE TEENS: THE ULTIMATE TEENAGE SUCCESS GUIDE. | 9.78148E+12 | Paper |  | 17.99 USD |
| 7 HABITS OF HIGHLY EFFECTIVE TEENS: THE ULTIMATE TEENAGE SUCCESS GUIDE. | 9.78148E+12 | eBook |  |  |
| ADOBE AUDITION CC: CLASSROOM IN A BOOK: THE OFFICIAL TRAINING WORKBOOK FROM ADOBE. | 9.78014E+12 | Paper | 2ND ED. | 59.99 USD |

I am able to merge the two dataframes so that the course info is available along with the book purchasing info. However, Dataframe B contains many different listings for the same book. I would like to bring the course info over to matching titles where the ISBN isn't the same. So in the example below, even though the ISBNs are different, the course info would appear for both versions of the title:

| Course Abbreviation | Course Number | Section Number | Course Name | Course Instructor | Course Seats | ISBN No | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CTEC | 107 | 825.0 | Skills for IT Success | Lott | 20.0 | 9781476764665 | 7 HABITS OF HIGHLY EFFECTIVE TEENS: THE ULTIMATE TEENAGE SUCCESS GUIDE. |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 7 HABITS OF HIGHLY EFFECTIVE TEENS: THE ULTIMATE TEENAGE SUCCESS GUIDE. |

What would be the best way to do this? The rows that need course info filled in are not always in the same location in relation to the rows that do have course info, so I don't think ffill or bfill will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by `ISBN No` will push the nulls to the bottom, then you can groupby title and ffill the data.

```
df.sort_values(by='ISBN No').groupby('Title').ffill()
```